# SQL Anywhere autoincrement reset

Tags: auto-increment, sqlanywhere

I've got a SQL Anywhere 9 database, and I would like to reset the autoincrement value on one of my columns to a specific number.

I guess I need the SQL-Anywhere equivalent of:

`ALTER TABLE foo AUTO_INCREMENT =100`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just so the answer is actually here, not just linked to:

Use the `sa_reset_identity` system procedure:

```
sa_reset_identity (
  [ table_name
  [, owner
  [, new_identity_value ] ] ]
)
```

Comment: Be sure to set new_identity_value to n-1 if you want the next value to be n e.g. set 0 to have a next value of 1.

Answer (score 1):

A google search turned up [this](http://books.google.com.mt/books?id=Vf_EgfsFw-8C&pg=PA17&lpg=PA17&dq=SQL+Anywhere+reset+autoincrement&source=bl&ots=ptljEdQRdW&sig=CU7TN7DGbnd6ikjCK7c9epCIOMs&hl=mt&ei=lCUkSo_mL5aasgaw7LnEBg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3). I have never used SQL Anywhere, so I'm afraid I can't help anymore.

Comment: Thanks, just pulled up http://www.ianywhere.com/developer/product_manuals/sqlanywhere/0902/en/html/dbrfen9/00000662.htm and found the specific syntax for system functions

Answer (score 0):

The correct system procedure is `sa_reset_identity`

```
CALL sa_reset_identity('table_name', 'user_name', new_start_value -1);
```

For example, you have a table called **CITIES**, a user **DBA** and you want the autoincrement to start with value **1**. Your code would be:

```
CALL sa_reset_identity('cities', 'DBA', 0);
```

**Source**: http://www.sqlines.com/sybase-asa/autoincrement_identity